# Matlab: using readtable to import excel dates/datetimes as displayed within excel

Tags: excel, matlab, datetime

I have (many) excel files/sheets with (many) variables representing datetimes. Due to real-world data, the time component isn't always available, resulting in individual excel cells being formatted as either "Date" (dd/MM/yyyy) or "Custom" (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm):

[example excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6foGZ.png)

In light of this inconsistent formatting I'm trying to import these data into Matlab as text rather than datetime (and will deal with separation of date and time components later on). However, *readtable* with suggested *setvaropts* returns something I wasn't expecting:

```
opts = detectImportOptions(xls_path);
opts=setvaropts(opts,{'my_datetime_var','excel_format','excel_display'},'Type','char');
data_as_char=readtable(xls_path,opts)

data_as_char =

  2×3 table

          my_datetime_var                  excel_format               excel_display    
    ___________________________    ____________________________    ____________________

    {'2023-03-08 00:00:00.000'}    {'Date'                    }    {'08/03/2023'      }
    {'2023-03-09 12:01:00.000'}    {'Custom: dd/mm/jjjj uu:mm'}    {'09/03/2023 12:01'}
```

Besides the altered display format of *my_datetime_var* relative to *excel_display*, the more critical issue is that a time component of "00:00:00.000" is introduced when it shouldn't.

The older function *xlsread* does keep information as displayed within excel (but its use is now discouraged):

```
[~,txt] = xlsread(xls_path)

txt =

  3×3 cell array

    {'my_datetime_var'    }    {'excel_format'            }    {'excel_display'     }
    {'08/03/2023'         }    {'Date'                    }    {'"08/03/2023"'      }
    {'09/03/2023 12:01:00'}    {'Custom: dd/mm/jjjj uu:mm'}    {'"09/03/2023 12:01"'}
```

How do I import excel date/datetime information using *readtable* as displayed within excel (without introducing time components)?

Also tried reading in as datetime with various inputformats, but datetime also introduces a time component.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You describe how `readtable` "introduces a time component", but all it's doing is using the `datetime` MATLAB datatype, which includes data and time. Regardless what your data _looks_ like (time or no time), any further processing is going to have to treat a date with no time as midnight, or something else. What are you expecting to do with this data downstream? To preserve the text formatting forever you'd have to keep the datetimes as chars, which seems impractical for manipulation

Comment: @Wolfie not quite I think (though thanks for pointing out XY). I explicitly forbid using Matlab's `datetime` variable type by using `setvaropts(opts,'Type','char')`. indeed, the imported data has variable type `char`, but the problem is that the data no longer reflect the formatting from Excel. my question is simply: how do I import dates/datetimes into Matlab **as shown in Excel** using the recommended `readtable` function? (your point regarding further processing of datetime information is a different issue and not my question)

Comment: Can you use the `'FileType','text'` option to force it away from interpreting as any sort of Excel data? Would probs only work if this was a csv not an Excel file. It would be helpful for you to include your MATLAB version in the question, as the behaviour of `readtable` changed slightly in R2020a. It would be good to know what the _raw_ data looks like, without Excel doing any formatting on top, because it's likely that's what MATLAB is actually reading (and probably why my `'text'` suggestion will fail)

Comment: Matlab version R2022a. as you suspected, `'FileType', 'Text'` fails (sth is imported, but just gibberish). unfortunately, the raw data is truly Excel with its weird autodetected date and/or datetime formatting, but the presence/absence of the time component has _value_ for downstream processing. so I'm just trying to retain that information by importing however it's displayed within Excel as text/char/string (i.e., something literal). very surprised that's so difficult and/or uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation for `xlsread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) the banner which recommends against using `xlsread` does suggest `readcell` as an alternative. This appears to give the result you want:

[image: spreadsheet]

```
c = readcell( 'Book1.xlsx', 'sheet', 'Sheet1', 'range', 'B2:B4' )
```

Output:

```
c =

  3×1 cell array

    {'Date'                }
    {[03-May-2012         ]}
    {[04-May-2012 15:30:00]}
```

---

From your comment, it looks like it's going to be very hard to reproduce your issue without your actual spreadsheet. There's probably two approaches, one is to assume all midnight datetimes should be formatted as a date only, since Excel is ultimately storing all dates and datetimes as number of days since Jan 1st 1900, which will have no fractional part for date-only entries. That feels a bit ropey, so **I think the only thing left is to read the actual format data out of Excel**, here is one way to do that from MATLAB:

```
% Connect to Excel
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
fn = 'Book1.xlsx';
    
% Make sure workbook is open, get a handle on it
Workbook = [];
for ii = 1:Excel.Workbooks.Count
    if strcmpi( fn, obj.Excel.Workbooks.Item(ii).Name )
        Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Item(ii);
        break;
    end
end
if isempty( Workbook )
    Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open( fullfile(pwd,fn) );
end

%% Read in data
% Specify the range
rg = 'B2:C4';
sht = 'Sheet1';
% Read the data
data = Workbook.Sheets.Item(sht).Range(rg).Value;
% Loop over the cells and read the format
ncells = Workbook.Sheets.Item(sht).Range(rg).Cells.Count;
% MATLAB is column-major, Excel is row-major. So transpose before and after
% the loop to get the correct alignment between data and fmt.
fmt = cell(size(data)).';
for ii = 1:ncells
    fmt{ii} = Workbook.Sheets.Item(sht).Range(rg).Cells.Item(ii).NumberFormat;
end
fmt = fmt.';
```

**There are plenty of existing questions about Excel interaction, the most interesting bit of this snippet should be the final loop.** You can `edit xlsread` or use another tutorial to see about handling the Excel workbook interaction more gracefully.

In your code, you can then handle any formatting things however you want, since you know the actual format type Excel is using.

Output:

[image: data and format variables]

Comment: not for me. time component still being introduced with `readcell` when Excel doesn't have one, both following your code and when using `setvaropts` to request variables being read in as `char`.

Comment: one small comment re assuming midnight: of course (bc why not) there are instances where 00:00 was entered as an actual valid time, so need to be able to separate those from where no time is available. anyway, last suggestion looks very promising: will try to test soon.